# How can I allow spaces in a Django username regex?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to allow spaces to be accepted into the username field of the default django.contrib.auth.models User, other people have asked directly or similar questions before: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911087/how-can-i-allow-spaces-in-a-django-username), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214453/allowing-the-character-in-usernames-in-the-django-admin-interface), and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828177/django-auth-manipulate-model-fields-allow-space-in-usernames). I have tried to implement these suggestions however I cannot seem to find a good example of how to get this to work.

From what I understand I need to change the regex in the username field validator, to do this I can override the UserCreationForm from contrib.auth.forms to implement a different field for username and provide my own validation. (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828177/django-auth-manipulate-model-fields-allow-space-in-usernames) answer).

How specifically do I do this?

for reference, this is currently what I am using as a signup form:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    This form class is for creating a player
    """
    username = forms.CharField(label='Gamertag', max_length=16, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Gamertag', 'class': 'form-input'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'form-input', 'type':'email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'form-input'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'email',
                  'password']
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'A user with that email already exists.')
        return email
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you running?

Comment: My version of Django is 1.10.1

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't trying to modify the fields on the default User class, the other Jonathan's answer for post 1.10 is good except for a couple small mistakes.

- `username_validator = MyValidator` needs to be `username_validator = MyValidator()` or the validator will fail silently and allow anything.
- The dash should be the last character in the brackets or escaped (otherwise it will act as a range).
- A space should be used instead of the `\s` character, which would allow any whitespace (including tabs and newlines).

The final code looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator

class MyValidator(UnicodeUsernameValidator):
    regex = r'^[\w.@+\- ]+$'

class MyUser(User):
    username_validator = MyValidator()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True  # If no new field is added.
```

(simply replace `UnicodeUsernameValidator` with `ASCIIUsernameValidator` if using Python 2). Note that the dot is within brackets, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

If you are modifying the fields on your User class, you are probably subclassing `AbstractUser` and you can't use `proxy = True`. This means the `username` field on `AbstractUser` will use the `username_validator` declared on `AbstractUser`, not yours. To fix this, you pretty much have to re-declare `username` on your model, like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _    

class MyValidator(UnicodeUsernameValidator):
    regex = r'^[\w.@+\- ]+$'

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username_validator = MyValidator()
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
            error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

Make sure you run makemigrations and migrate afterwards.

I've tried a number of ways to change the validators on username after it has already been declared, but haven't had any luck, so it looks like this is the best way for now.

Comment: Pls. change regex  to  r'^[\w\.@+\-\s]+$'  I can't due to silly rule that edits must be 6 characters or more ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll retest a few things with that. I foolishly just copied the other answer without thinking about the regex string.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the user where the validator exists. The following code should work for Django 1.9.

With this user below you should be able to use `MyUser` instead of `User` for the form that you wrote.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core import validators

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    validators=[
                validators.RegexValidator(
                    r'^[\w.@+-\s]+$',
                    _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                      'letters, numbers, spaces ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
                ),
            ],

    class Meta:
        proxy = True  # If no new field is added.
```

If you want to do it in Django 1.10 you'll have to change the code slightly. In Django 1.10 a new property was added `username_validator` and you'll have to override that. You can read more about it in the [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username_validator).

If you're using python2 you'll have to override `ASCIIUsernameValidator` or if you using python3 you'll have to override `UnicodeUsernameValidator`. For simplicity I'll assume that you're using python3. You can see the source code of the validation [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.1/django/contrib/auth/validators.py#L19-L26).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator

class MyValidator(UnicodeUsernameValidator):
    regex = r'^[\w.@+-\s]+$'

class MyUser(User):
    username_validator = MyValidator

    class Meta:
        proxy = True  # If no new field is added.
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your response! unfortunately my Django is version 1.10, it the method to change the validator similar?

Comment: I have placed this code in forms.py and models.py however I am now getting an error: `TypeError: Abstract base class containing model fields not permitted for proxy model 'MyUser'.`. I am fairly new to django, sorry if I am doing something obviously wrong

Comment: by removing the `proxy = True` part I was able to get the project to compile, however I was still unable to signup a user with spaces in their username. I copied in the code above into my forms.py page and replaced "model = User" with "model = MyUser" for my signUpFrom, however it still does not work.

Comment: My bad, could you try subclassing `User` instead of `AbstractUser`. Starting with proxy = True.

Comment: ah ok that now compiles with the proxy=True, I have now replaced that and User in the Meta of SignUpForm:
    `class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['username',
                  'email',
                  'password']
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }`

unfortunately it seems to have had no affect, whenever I try and signup a username with a space in it I still get the error: "Enter a valid username. This value may contain only English letters, numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters."

Comment: Reading this comment chain, I think you're running into the same issue that I did. I've posted my workaround as a full answer.